# Admob App Open ads vs rewarded ads in mobile game

Tags: mobile, admob, ads, payment, rewardedvideoad

I made a game and I been seesaw between App Open Ads and Rewarded ads. I read the rewarded ads making more money but I don't want to limit the player. When s/he finished watched the ad, S/he will get the price at both. But which of should I pick? I want to make more money but also I don't want to limit the player. Player could decide to close the ad and don't get the price. But if I pick app open ads, do I earn less money?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Open Ads, only used when the player open the app at the beginning.

Rewarded ads, should be used in exchange of a reward (could be coins or points)

So it depends on your game.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. Do you know how do I enable the close button before the video finished in the rewareded ad, i am using unity.